# Is this homebrew Elementalist Fighter class balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, class, homebrew-review

I have been using this site for awhile as it has been a great reference in my own campaign that I'm DMing myself and I figured that this would be a great time to ask my first question.

I'm participating in another campaign that is being run by another one of my friends. For our campaign my brother had a concept for a different kind of character than was offered in any of the published material. So I worked with my DM to make a homebrew class that fulfilled his idea, but was also as balanced as possible. We based our new class on a combination of the Battle Master Fighter and a bit of the Barbarian class. Most of the class is just a reskinned version of the BM Fighter, but we also reskinned the Barbarian's Rage ability.

Here is a Homebrewery link to my class: https://homebrewery.naturalcrit.com/share/rkbnPP027Q

So my question to all of you people is what do you think about the balance and viability of this class?

As a side note, I have no problems with anybody using this class for their own class if they find it balanced.

---

The class:

## The Elementalist Fighter

#### Elementalist Fighter Leveling Table

(Here, *Prof. Bonus* means proficiency bonus, *Sup Die* means Superiority Die, *Imbue Dmg* means Imbue Damage.)

$$
\begin{array}{r|l|l|l|l|l|l}
\text{Lv.} & \text{Prof.} & \text{Maneuvers} & \text{Sup} & \text{Imbue} & \text{Imbue} & \text{Features} \\
 & \text{Bonus} & \text{Known} & \text{Die} & \text{Casts} & \text{Dmg} \\
\hline
1 & -2 & - & - & 2 & -2 & \text{Fighting Style, Weapon Bond,} \\
  &    &   &   &   &    & \text{Imbue Weapon} \\
\hline
2 & -2 & - & - & 2 & -2 & \text{Action Surge (1x)} \\
\hline
3 & -2 & 3 & 4d8 & 3 & -2 & \text{Combat Superiority,} \\
  &    &   &     &   &    & \text{Second Wind, Voice of Conflux} \\
\hline
4 & -2 & 3 & 4d8 & 3 & -2 & \text{Ability Score Improvement} \\
\hline
5 & -3 & 3 & 4d8 & 3 & -2 & \text{Extra Attack (x1)} \\
\hline
6 & -3 & 3 & 4d8 & 4 & -2 & \text{Ability Score Improvement} \\
\hline
7 & -3 & 5 & 5d8 & 4 & -2 & \text{Ancient Blade} \\
\hline
8 & -3 & 5 & 5d8 & 4 & -2 & \text{Ability Score Improvement} \\
\hline
9 & -4 & 5 & 5d8 & 4 & -3 & \text{Elemental Incarnation} \\
\hline
10 & -4 & 7 & 5d10 & 4 & -3 & \text{Improved Combat Superiority} \\
\hline
11 & -4 & 7 & 5d10 & 4 & -3 & \text{Extra Attack (x2)} \\
\hline
12 & -4 & 7 & 5d10 & 5 & -3 & \text{Ability Score Improvement} \\
\hline
13 & -5 & 7 & 5d10 & 5 & -3 & \text{Improved Elemental Incarnation} \\
\hline
14 & -5 & 7 & 5d10 & 5 & -3 & \text{Ability Score Improvement} \\
\hline
15 & -5 & 9 & 6d10 & 5 & -3 & \text{Relentless} \\
\hline
16 & -5 & 9 & 6d10 & 6 & -4 & \text{Ability Score Improvement} \\
\hline
17 & -6 & 9 & 6d10 & 6 & -4 & \text{Action Surge (x2),} \\
   &    &   &      &   &    & \text{Elemental Explosion} \\
\hline
18 & -6 & 9 & 6d12 & 6 & -4 & \text{Improved Combat Superiority} \\
\hline
19 & -6 & 9 & 6d12 & 6 & -4 & \text{Ability Score Improvement} \\
\hline
20 & -6 & 9 & 6d12 & \infty & -4 & \text{Extra Attack (x3)} \\
\end{array}
$$

- **Hit Dice:** 1d10 per elementalist fighter level
- **Hit Points at 1st Level:** 10 + your Constitution modifier
- **Hit Points at Higher Levels:** 1d10 (or 6) + your Constitution modifier per elementalist fighter level after the 1st.

#### Proficiencies

- **Armor:** All armor, Shields
- **Weapons:** All weapons
- **Tools:** None
- **Saving Throws:** Strength, Constitution
- **Skills:** Choose two skills from Acrobatics, Athletics, Arcana, Insight, Investigation, Perception, and Survival.

#### Equipment

You start with the following equipment, in addition to the equipment granted by your background:

- *(a)* chain mail or *(b)* leather, longbow, and 20 arrows
- *(a)* a martial weapon and a shield or *(b)* two martial weapons
- *(a)* a light crossbow and 20 bolts or *(b)* two handaxes
- *(a)* a dungeoneer's pack or *(b)* an explorer's pack

#### Imbue Weapon

Starting at 1st level, as a bonus action, you can imbue your weapon with an element.

The imbuement must be Acid, Cold, Fire, Lightning, or Thunder. At level 7, you gain the ability to imbue your weapon with Necrotic, Psychic, or Radiant energy. You can use this feature a number of times as specified in the *Imbue Casts* column of your class table. You regain all expended uses after a long rest.

While your weapon is imbued, you gain the following benefits:

- You have advantage on Charisma checks and Charisma saving throws.
- When you make a melee weapon attack with an imbued weapon, you gain a bonus to the damage roll as shown in the table above of your imbuement type.
- You have darkvision out to 30 feet if you don't have it already. If you have darkvision, it extends by 30 feet.
- You have resistance to Psychic damage and advantage on saving throws against being charmed.

#### Weapon Bond

Over the course of 1 hour short rest, you can bond a weapon to you. Once bonded, you cannot be disarmed unless you are incapacitated and if the weapon is on the same plane of existence, you can summon it to your hand as a bonus action. You can bond with up to two weapons at once.

#### Fighting Style

At 1st level, you can adopt a particular style of fighting as your specialty. Choose one of the following options. You can't take a Fighting Style option more than once, even if later you get to choose again.

- Defense
  While you are wearing armor, you gain a +1 bonus to AC.
- Dueling
  When you are wielding a melee weapon in one hand and no other weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon.
- Great Weapon Fighting
  When you roll a 1 or 2 on a damage die for an attack you make with a melee weapon that you are wielding with two hands, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll, even if the new roll is a 1 or a 2. The weapon must have the two-handed or versatile property for you to gain this benefit.
- Protection
  When a creature you can see attacks a target other than you that is within 5 feet of you, you can use your reaction to impose disadvantage on the attack roll. You must be wielding a shield.
- Two-Weapon Fighting
  When you engage in two-weapon fighting, you can add your ability modifier to the damage of the second attack.

#### Action Surge

Starting at second level, on your turn, you can take one additional action on top of your regular action and a possible bonus action. Once you use this feature, you must finish a short or long rest before you can use it again. Starting at 17th level, you can use it twice before a rest, but only once on the same turn.

#### Second Wind

At third level, on your turn, you can use a bonus action to regain hit points equal to 1d10 + your elementalist fighter level. Once you use this feature, you must finish a short or long rest before you can use it again.

#### Combat Superiority

- Maneuvers
  You learn three special maneuvers. You can use only one maneuver per attack.

  You learn two additional maneuvers of your choice at 7th, 10th, and 15th level. Each time you learn new maneuvers, you can also replace one maneuver you know with a different one.
- Superiority Dice
  Starting at 3rd level, you start with 4 superiority dice, which are d8s, and you expend one whenever you use a maneuver. You regain them all when you finish a short or long rest.

  You gain another superiority die at 7th level and one more at 15th level.
- Saving Throws
  Some of your maneuvers require your target to make a saving throw to resist the maneuver's effects. The saving throw DC is calculated as follows:

  Maneuver save DC: 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Charisma modifier

#### Voice of Conflux

At 3rd level, your understanding of the elementals has grown to their language. You learn Aquan, Auran, Ignan, Primordial, and Terran.

#### Ability Score Improvement

When you reach 4th level, and again at 6th, 8th, 12th, 14th, 16th, and 19th level, you can increase one ability score of your choice by 2, or you can increase two Ability Scores of your choice by 1. As normal, you can't increase an ability score above 20 using this feature.

#### Extra Attack

Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn. The number of attacks increases to three when you reach 11th level in this class and to four when you reach 20th level in this class.

#### Ancient Blade

By 7th level you have learned to tap into the history of a weapon in order to gain different benefits. The more storied the blade and the deeper your understanding of it the more benefits you gain. Depending on the weapon, there are 3 tiers of benefits that you can achieve. For example, the weapon of a common bandit may not give any history, but the weapon of an extremely significant historical figure might allow up to the third tier of benefits.

Examples and suggested characteristics can be found at the end of this guide.

You may only gain the benefits of one bonded weapon at a time. You can change this benefit to your other bonded weapon (if you have one) after a long rest.

#### Elemental Incarnation

Beginning at 9th level, you can use an action to heavily channel elemental power for 10 minutes. Due to the immense amount of effort this incarnation requires, you gain a point of exhaustion after using this ability. You may only use this ability once per long rest. Choose one of the following options.

- **Flame:** Flames race across your body, shedding bright light in a 30-foot radius and dim light for an additional 30 feet for the spell’s duration. The flames don’t harm you. Until the spell ends, you gain the following benefits.

  - You have resistance to both fire and cold damage.
  - Any creature that moves within 5 feet of you for the first time on a turn or ends its turn there takes 1d10 fire damage.
  - You can use your action to create a line of fire 15 feet long and 5 feet wide extending from you in a direction you choose. Each creature in the line must make a Dexterity saving throw. A creature takes 4d8 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.
- **Ice:** Until the spell ends, ice rimes your body, and you gain the following benefits.

  - You have resistance to both fire and cold damage.
  - You can move across difficult terrain created by ice or snow without spending extra movement.
  - The ground in a 10-foot radius around you is icy and is difficult terrain for creatures other than you. The radius moves with you.
  - You can use your action to create a 15-foot cone of freezing wind extending from your outstretched hand in a direction you choose. Each creature in the cone must make a Constitution saving throw. A creature takes 4d6 cold damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. A creature that fails its save against this effect has its speed halved until the start of your next turn.
- **Stone:** Until the spell ends, bits of rock spread across your body, and you gain the following benefits.

  - You have resistance to bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage from nonmagical weapons.
  - You can use your action to create a small earthquake on the ground in a 15-foot radius centered on you. Other creatures on that ground must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or be knocked prone.
  - You can move across difficult terrain made of earth or stone without spending extra movement. You can move through solid earth or stone as if it was air and without destabilizing it, but you can’t end your movement there. If you do so, you are ejected to the nearest unoccupied space, this spell ends, and you are stunned until the end of your next turn.
- **Wind:** Until the spell ends, wind whirls around you, and you gain the following benefits.

  - You gain the ability to fly in short bursts. You gain a fly speed of 60' per round, but you must end your turn on solid land or plummet to the ground and take fall damage.
  - Ranged weapon attacks made against you have disadvantage on the attack roll.
  - You can use your action to create a 15-foot cube of swirling wind centered on a point you can see within 60 feet of you. Each creature in that area must make a Constitution saving throw. A creature takes 2d10 bludgeoning damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. If a Large or smaller creature fails the save, that creature is also pushed up to 10 feet away from the center of the cube.

#### Improved Combat Superiority

When you reach 10th level, your superiority dice turn into a d10. When you reach level 18, your superiority dice become a d12.

#### Improved Elemental Incarnation

Starting at level 13, you have spent a lot of time working on your *Elemental Incarnation*. Although you can still only cast it once per long rest, the effort no longer leave you exhausted.

#### Relentless

Starting at level 15, whenever you roll for initiative and have zero superiority dice, you get 1 superiority die back.

#### Elemental Explosion

Requires 1+ superiority dice and expends all your remaining superiority dice.

Starting at level 17, you can use an action to cause your weapon to explode with elemental energy. Every enemy within 15' of you must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failure, the target takes your imbuement damage and 2d8 damage for every superiority die spent. The damage is of the imbuement type.

Once you use this ability, you must finish a long rest before you can use it again.

## Maneuvers

In order to use a maneuver that creates elemental energy, you must be using a bonded weapon. If your weapon is not bonded, you can only use the following maneuvers: Commanding Strike, Evasive Footwork, Feinting Attack, Goading Attack, Precision Attack, or Riposte.

#### Chained Attack

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can spend one superiority die to call upon the power of lightning and attempt to damage another creature with the same attack. Choose another target within 5' of the original target. If the original attack roll would have hit the second target, it takes lightning damage equal to the superiority die roll as lightning arcs between the two targets.

#### Commanding Strike

When you take the Attack action on your turn, you can forego one of your attacks and instead direct a companion to strike using your bonus action. Choose a friendly creature who can see or hear you and expend one superiority die. That creature can immediately use its reaction to make a weapon attack, adding the superiority die's result to the attack's damage.

#### Disarming Attack

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can spend one superiority die to call upon the power of fire. You add the superiority die's roll to your damage, and the target must make a Strength saving throw. On a failure, one object of your choice in the target's possession becomes too hot to hold and they are forced to drop it. The object falls at their feet.

#### Distracting Attack

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can spend one superiority die to call upon the power of thunder. You add the superiority die's roll to your damage, and the next attack against that target has advantage thanks to the booming thunder providing a distraction.

#### Elemental Bulwark

You throw attacking out the window for this turn. Use an action on this turn to slam your weapon on the ground, calling out to the elements for even more protection. Expend a superiority die. Until the start of your next turn, a shield of elemental rocks covers you and creatures of your choice within 10 feet, protecting their weaker points and reduces the damage that they take by your roll - your Charisma modifier.

#### Elemental Shield

When you or another creature are damaged by another creature's melee attack, you can use your reaction to call out to the elements for protection. Spend a superiority die and reduce the damage that you take by the number rolled + your Charisma modifier. You can instead use your reaction to shield an ally that you can see within 30 feet when they are attacked.

#### Elemental Slam

For this ability, you have mastered the ability to use differing amounts of power. Use a melee weapon to slam the ground in front of you and expend 1 or more superiority dice. You choose which element you call upon when you slam your weapon, causing different effects depending on the element used. Choose one of the following effects when you use this ability.

For this maneuver, your damage done equals your total rolled from your superiority dice - half of your Elementalist Fighter level (rounded down). In addition, if you use the maneuver associated with the element your weapon is imbued with, you can add your imbuement damage to the total.

- **Acid:**
  An explosion of acid sprays from the contact point between your weapon and the ground. Every creature in a 10' radius must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take your ability damage and has disadvantage on their next attack. On a successful save the target takes half damage and does not have disadvantage.
- **Cold:**
  An arctic blast chills the air around you. Every creature in a 10' radius must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take your ability damage and have their movement speed reduced to 0' as ice freezes their legs in place until they use an action to break free. On a successful save the target takes half damage and their speed is not reduced.
- **Fire:**
  Magma superheats the ground surrounding your weapon. Until the end of your next turn, the ground within a 10' radius becomes red hot. Any creature that starts or ends its turn within the radius takes your ability damage. On a successful save the target takes half damage.
- **Force (Requires level 7):**
  An exposion of force energy is released from the point of contact between your weapon and the ground. Every creature in a 10' radius must succeed on a Strength saving throw or take your ability damage and be pushed back 10'. On a successful save the target takes half damage and is not pushed back.
- **Lightning:**
  Creatures grouped around you only makes your lightning damage more powerful. Immune to lightning for this maneuver only, a column of lightning flashes down on you from above. Every creature of your choice in a 5' radius must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or take your ability damage (- 1d4 for every creature that you chose within the radius) as lightning arcs out from your body into theirs. On a successful save the target takes half damage.
- **Necrotic (Requires level 7):**
  Every creature of your choice in a 10' radius must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or take your ability damage. Half of the damage dealt is given back to you in the form of temporary hit points. On a successful save the target takes half damage and you do not gain any temporary hit points.
- **Psychic (Requires level 7):**
  Psychic energy erupts from the contact point between your weapon and the ground. Every creature of your choice in a 10' radius must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or take your ability damage and be forced to drop their weapon as they clutch their heads in terrible pain. On a successful save the target takes half damage and is not disarmed.
- **Radiant (Requires level 7):**
  A brilliant flash of light explodes at the contact between your weapon and the ground. Every creature in a 10' radius must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or take your ability damage and become blinded until the end of your next turn. On a successful save the target takes half damage and is not blinded.
- **Thunder:**
  A thunderclap erupts from the contact between your weapon and the ground. Every creature in a 10' radius must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or take your ability damage and become deafened until the end of your next turn. On a successful save the target takes half damage and is not deafened.

#### Evasive Footwork

When you move on your turn, you can spend a bonus action to expend a superiority die, adding the total to your AC until the start of your next turn.

#### Feinting Attack

You can expend one superiority die and use a bonus action on your turn to feint, choosing one creature within 5 feet of you as your target. Until the end of the turn, you have advantage on your next attack roll against that creature. If that attack hits, add the superiority die to the attack's damage roll.

#### Forceful Attack

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to attempt to knock the target down. You add the superiority die to the attack's damage roll and you call upon the power of force magic. If the target is Large or smaller, it must make a Strength saving throw or be knocked prone.

#### Furious Arc

You swing your weapon in a forward arc, calling upon the power of fire. Every creature in a 15' cone originating from your position must make a Dexterity saving throw, taking fire damage equal to the number rolled on your superiority die - your Charisma modifier on a failure, or half as much on a success.

#### Goading Attack

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die and attempt to goad your target into attacking you. You add the superiority die to the roll and the target must make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failure, the target has disadvantage on all attack rolls on targets other than you until the end of your next turn.

#### Icy Ground

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can spend one superiority die to call upon the power of frost. You add the superiority die's roll to your damage, and the ground surrounding you becomes coated in ice. Until the end of your next turn, every creature (excluding you) that starts or ends its turn within 10' of you must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or fall prone.

#### Lightning Reach

When you make a weapon attack on your turn, you can spend one superiority die to call upon the power of lightning to extend your reach by 5'. If the attack hits, you may add the superiority die's damage to the attack as your weapon gains an extra 5' of reach thanks to the pure lightning energy arcing off the blade.

#### Menacing Strike

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can spend one superiority die to cause necrotic energy to swirl around you. You add the superiority die's roll to your damage, and the target must make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failure, the creature is frightened of you until the end of your next turn.

#### Necrotic Strike (Requires level 7)

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can spend one superiority die to cause your blade to be surrounded by necrotic energy. You add the superiority die's roll to your damage, and the target must make a Constitution saving throw.

On a failure, the extra necrotic damage sucks the life force of the target out and you gain temporary hit points equal to half of the necrotic damage dealt. On a success, the superiority die damage is halved and the life essence is not transferred.

#### Poison Attack (Requires level 7)

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can spend one superiority die to draw on the ambient elements and concentrate them into a poisonous cloud. You add the superiority die's roll to your damage, and the target must make a Constitution saving throw. On a failure, the target becomes poisoned for 1 minute.

#### Precision Attack

When you make a weapon attack against a creature, you can expend one superiority die and add it to the roll. You can do this after you see the results of your roll, but before the DM tells you if it hits or misses.

#### Pushing Attack

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can spend one superiority die to call upon the power of force. You add the superiority die's roll to your damage, and the target (if it is a creature that is Large or smaller) must make a Strength saving throw. On a failure, it is pushed back 15'.

#### Radiant Strike (Requires level 7)

When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can spend one superiority die to cause your blade to be surrounded by radiant energy. You add the superiority die's roll to your damage, and the target must make a Constitution saving throw. On a failure, the light flashes so brightly that the target is considered Blinded until the end of your next turn.

#### Rally (Requires level 7)

On your turn, you can use a bonus action and expend one superiority die to call upon the renewing elements of nature to reinvigorate one of your companions. When you do so, choose a friendly creature who can see or hear you. That creature gains temporary hit points equal to your superiority die roll - your Charisma modifier.

#### Riposte

When a creature misses you with a melee attack, you can use your reaction and expend one superiority die to make a melee attack against the creature. If you hit, you add the superiority die to the attack's damage roll.

#### Swift Step

When you make a melee attack against a creature, you can expend one superiority die to invoke the element of air to bolster a companion's movement temporarily. Add the die damage to your attack, then choose one creature who can hear you. You shout out a challenge to their attackers, distracting them just long enough for your ally, bolstered by the swirling wind, to use their reaction and immediately move up to half of their movement without provoking opportunity attacks, with the goal of moving out of a troubling situation or to move into a more advantageous position.

## Example Weapons

#### Greataxe (Example)

History: The more storied the blade, the more tiers can be unlocked. For example, a bandit's sword may not lead to any tiers being unlocked for that weapon, but some extremely important historical figure's axe may be hiding incredible amounts of potential and can be unlocked up to tier 3. The rate of advancement, potential for unlocking tiers, and the rewards for unlocking each tier ultimately lies with the DM.

- Tier 1: Often unlocking this tier ability will grant the wielder proficiency in one or more languages, tools, or skills.
- Tier 2: Often unlocking this tier ability will grant the ability to cast a non-combat spell, such as *Speak with Animals* or *Comprehend Languages*.
- Tier 3: Often unlockig this tier ability will grant the wielder a combat benefit. This could be anything ranging from a simple attack or damage bonus, or the ability to cast a spell through the blade.

#### Widowmaker (Dagger)

History: This blade was used by the Drow assassin Gwyherd who was particularly cruel and effective.

- Tier 1: Upon unlocking this tier, the wielder gains proficiency with Thieves' Tools and the Poisoner's Kit.
- Tier 2: Upon unlocking this tier, the wielder gains the ability to cast *Minor Illusion* as a cantrip.
- Tier 3: Upon unlocking this final tier, the wielder gains the ability to use *Disintigrate* as a 6th level spell once per long rest.

#### Bloodwake (Rapier)

History: This blade was used in countless naval battles by a ship's captain (a very surly dwarf). He was an extremely accomplished fencer, and commanded his armada to many naval victories.

- Tier 1: Upon unlocking this tier, the wielder gains proficiency in Navigator's Tools and Water Vehicles.
- Tier 2: Upon unlocking this tier, the wielder gains the ability to cast *Unseen Servant* once per long rest.
- Tier 3: No benefits.

#### Carver (Handaxe)

History: This blade was owner by a simple farmer, but it was passed down through his family for generations. It was used to defend their family farm countless times against predators and bandits.

- Tier 1: Upon unlocking this tier, the wielder gains proficiency in one standard language of the DM's choice.
- Tier 2–3: No benefits.

#### Bandit Sword (Scimitar)

History: This blade was used by a bandit who liked to attack caravans passing by. It gives no tier benefits.

- Tier 1–3: No benefits.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Just so you know, most of the formatting in your post is not working right now; StackExchange uses markdown for formatting. See here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: I'm aiming for answers about the balance of my homebrew class against any officially released class of the same level.

Comment: @SirUlrichVonLiechtenstein Have you considered building an alternative specialty for the Fighter instead of an entire class? 5E's split into class and subclass makes it a lot easier to build a balanced class by limiting the abilities gained. That way it wouldn't need to be evaluated level by level, but only on the levels where the class grants a special ability. In general it's best practice to build a subclass for an existing class than to build a new class outright.

Comment: Yes we both considered it, but we thought that this class concept was different enough that a new class was required.

Comment: -1; because I don't understand how there is any doubt this class is unbalanced. It takes an entire class+subclass, then adds more stuff.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## The Elementalist Fighter class is more powerful at every level than a standard Battlemaster Fighter.

I'm using the Battlemaster Archetype as a reference point as the OP has stated that it is an influence on the homebrew class design and because the class features closely mirror that of the Battlemaster.

TLDR; Elementalist Fighter blends almost all of the features of a Battlemaster, adds a sprinkle of Barbarian and then adds a tonne of powerful abilities to boot.

- Second Wind comes 2 levels later, decreasing survivability at 1st and 2nd level, before returning to the status quo at 3rd.
- Weapon Bond is almost identical to the Eldritch Knight feature and comes 2 levels early. It somewhat undermines one of the EK's unique features but is not too major.
- Imbue Weapon is a reskinned Barbarian Rage, the quintessential Barbarian feature. It is more offensive focused than defensive. There doesn't appear to be an end condition, but I'll assume it's the same as Rage. Almost everything here feels out of flavour for an elemental focused fighter. Psychic resistance, temporary darkvision, changing the advantage on checks and saves to Charisma, and advantage on saves against being charmed are not, in my opinion, things I would associate with a class called "Elementalist Fighter". Mechanically, choosing the additional damage's type is strong as it somewhat enables low-level melee fighters to circumvent physical damage resistances, one of their greatest banes. It is somewhat comparable to the 3rd level Elemental Weapon spell, minus the to hit bonus and magical weapon consideration. Losing the physical damage resistance of Rage is not a suitable drawback, as Fighters are much more capable of achieving high ACs at low levels than Barbarians, through heavy armour, shields, and fighting styles. So the loss of defensive abilities is negated by the classes intrinsic high AC and the damage capabilities are greater than the standard Rage, with some odd extras thrown in.
- Maneuvers. Having extra restrictions on maneuvers is sure to only cause confusion. The save DC being Charisma based is also quite unexpected and again outside of the classes flavour. Some of the new maneuvers are far above the current power level. Elemental Slam stands out as particularly egregious. Fighters lack AoE as a balance requirement. Giving them access to AoE which does good damage for a relatively low resource cost, is definitely going to cause them to be overpowered relative to another fighter of the same level. In conjunction with the powerful secondary abilities that many of the damage type Slams offer, I don't know why you wouldn't pick this maneuver over any other.
- Ancient Blade doesn't have any real balance concerns. It does, however, cause a great deal more work for your DM, which is something that I would consider poor design. Know your Enemy of the Battlemaster is pretty whatever, but it doesn't cause any additional preparation or forethought that could be used on the game as a whole, instead of one character.
- Elemental Incarnation is absolutely insane. Indomitable is already a strong class feature, and EI blows it out of the water. It evaluates to casting one of the Investitures of X spells, without the need for concentration, once per day, at the cost of one level of exhaustion. And this is in a non-casting class, 2 levels earlier than a full caster could. The sheer damage output and/or utility that this feature could provide in its 10 minutes is incredible. Especially considering most conditions that require a save also give one each turn. Potentially missing a turn or two is well worth this.
- Elemental Explosion is again powerful because it gives Fighters access to powerful AoE at a relatively low cost.

If given the choice to play a Battlemaster or an Elementalist Fighter, the Elementalist is the clear winner. With its access to cheap AoE and additional damage output, it does everything a Battlemaster does and more. It suffers from a lack of identity, borrowing iconic features from other classes, and also having a mix of features that don't resound with the classes core concept.

Comment: @the dark wander I see EE as a defensive feature, rather than offensive. It's the "oopsy, I got myself surrounded and need to clear a path/thin the herd" feature. Having to blow all of your superiority dice isn't always efficient, but at that level you regain one at the start of each combat, so you're not totally being left high and dry and the feature is almost always an option to the player.